# Update Jetpack Compose list with scroll position reset

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my app I have list of items shown with LazyColumn. My list can update fields and sometime reorder items. Whenever I have reorder of items I need to show list with first item at the top. I came up with setup like the one below. List scrolls to the top only on the first reorder event. On consecutive list update with `reorder = true`, my list not scrolling to the top. What is the better approach in Compose to reset list scroll position (or even force rebuilding compose list) by sending state from ViewModel?

```
class ViewItemsState(val items: List<ViewItem>, val scrollToTop: Boolean)

class ExampleViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    
    var itemsLiveData = MutableLiveData<ViewItemsState>()

}

@Composable
fun ExampleScreen(viewModel: ExampleViewModel = viewModel()) {

    val itemState  by viewModel.itemsLiveData.observeAsState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    if (itemState.scrollToTop) {
        LaunchedEffect(coroutineScope) {
            Log.e("TAG", "TopCoinsScreen: scrollToTop" )
            listState.scrollToItem(0)
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(state = listState) {
        items(itemState.items) { item ->
            ItemCompose(
                item.name,
                item.value
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you suppose to scroll item after list is drawn ? Something like `view.post`?

Comment: I don't see you resetting `scrollToTop`, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Generally this approach should work

Comment: @PhilipDukhov what do you mean by reseting? I just update list and set parameter `scrollToTop  = true or false`.

Comment: @Rafael I'm talking about settings it to `false` after the list is scrolled. The may be a case when you not really updating it and just setting to true many times in a row, in this case it shouldn't scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Recomposition is triggered only when a state changes.

Two things to fix in this,

1. Reset `scrollToTop` to `false` once scrolling completes.
2. Store `scrollToTop` in the view model as a `MutableState`, `LiveData`, `Flow`, or any other reactive element.

Currently `scrollToTop` is stored as a boolean in a data class object. Resetting the value will not trigger a Composable recomposition.

Example code with sample data,

```
class ViewItemsState(
    val items: List<String>,
)

class ExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var _itemsLiveData =
        MutableLiveData(
            ViewItemsState(
                items = Array(20) {
                    it.toString()
                }.toList(),
            )
        )
    val itemsLiveData: LiveData<ViewItemsState>
        get() = _itemsLiveData

    private var _scrollToTop = MutableLiveData(false)
    val scrollToTop: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _scrollToTop

    fun updateScrollToTop(scroll: Boolean) {
        _scrollToTop.postValue(scroll)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ExampleScreen(
    viewModel: ExampleViewModel = ExampleViewModel(),
) {
    val itemState by viewModel.itemsLiveData.observeAsState()
    val scrollToTop by viewModel.scrollToTop.observeAsState()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = scrollToTop,
    ) {
        if (scrollToTop == true) {
            listState.scrollToItem(0)
            viewModel.updateScrollToTop(false)
        }
    }

    Column {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        ) {
            items(itemState?.items.orEmpty()) { item ->
                Text(
                    text = item,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                )
            }
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                viewModel.updateScrollToTop(true)
            },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Scroll")
        }
    }
}
```